# Prevent content to scroll beneath a fixed navbar

Tags: css, scroll, navbar

This page http://alsotoday.com/roemerstrasse/ has a fixed bootstrap navbar, which should stay fixed, so the video in the background can shine through it. When scrolling the content all the way up, it will go beneath the navbar, which is not favourable. Anybody know, how to create an upper margin for the content, so it will scroll only just beneath the navbar without changing the navbar to not-fixed?

Edit 1:
main-area-video and panel_container (meanwhile called main-area) are both height 100%, because each, the video and the tiles should fill a screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your page is always at 100% height and the only thing getting scrolled is the content you could just make it `absolute` instead of `fixed`.

But since you asked for a solution with a `fixed` position just add an `margin` to the content wrapper.

So to be clear: add `margin-top: {MENU_HEIGHT}px` to the content div, replacing `{MENU_HEIGHT}` with the actual height of your menu or the desired distance from it.

Comment: Does that work on your side, when you edit the code in the Inspector? It does not work here, when I enter a margin-top to either main-area-video or panel_container.

Comment: Yes, I'm guessing that you are setting the height OVER 100% by adding the margin-top, so you get 2 scrollbars instead of just one in the content.

Comment: Try the following, add a margin-top: 100px; to your .panel_container and set the height to: height: calc(100% - 150px);

Comment: Yeah, thanks, height: calc(100% -150px) works (kudos also to @trichetriche, whose answer also includes that).

Comment: I'm disappointed you didn't consider my answer, as it has an example you can see and a clear code. :(

Comment: @Boratznan 's answer's increment to my code was smaller and easier for me to implement.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this ? In this snippet, the articles will not go behind the navbar, and only the content is scrollable. This is how SPA are supposed to work, for instance.

**EDIT** I added an opacity to the navbar so you can see, nothing is behind it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 12px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
  <div class="article"></div>
</div>
```